# C++ cast to a more precise type and lose accuracy?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

Consider two way of computing something:

1. data in double precision
   -> apply a function with double precision temporaries
   -> return result
2. data in double precision
   -> cast to long double
   -> apply a function with long double precision temporaries
   -> cast to double
   -> return result

Can the second solution give a less accurate result compared to the first one and if yes in what case?

Comment: A double result is a double result. Both have the same precision. You might be thinking of accuracy. This article has a nice target picture that I find pretty useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision

Comment: Can anyone cite me a platform where a `long double` is any larger / has more precision than a `double`? I can't think of one off of the top of my head, barring embedded programming.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: all the Windowses and Linuxes and BSDs on x86 when compiling with GCC.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - does it matter whether there _is_ (currently) any platform where they are different?  The question is about possible differences, which involves future platforms where there could be differences

Comment: Just tested on the platform I use (supercomputer) : sizeof(float) = 4
sizeof(double) = 8
sizeof(long double) = 16

Comment: @StevenBurnap: Thanks. I didn't mention it because I never used it, so I can't speak of it.

Comment: @Vincent, supercomputer? And I thought my new laptop worked well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Proof: Let c = 0x1p-53 + 0x1p-64. Evaluate 1+c-c-1 in double and in long double (of the common Intel format, with a 64-bit significand). In double, the result is 0, which is the mathematically exact answer. In long double, the result is -0x1p-64, which is wrong (and remains wrong when cast to double).

In double, 1+c adds slightly more than half the ULP (unit of least precision) of 1 to 1, so it produces 1 plus an ULP. Subtracting c subtracts slightly more than half an ULP, so the closest representable number (in double) to the result is 1, so 1 is produced. Then subtracting 1 yields 0.

In long double, 1+c adds 0x1p-53 plus half an ULP of 1.  (In long double, the ULP of 1 is 0x1p-63.)  Since the result is exactly the same distance from the two nearest representable numbers (in long double), the one with the low bit zero is returned, 1+0x1p-53. Then the exact result of subtracting c is 1 - 0x1p-64. This is exactly representable, so it is returned. Finally, subtracting 1 yields -0x1p-64.

Answer (score 0):

About `long double` the draft says:

> **3.9.1 Fundamental Types**
>
> **8** There are three floating point types: float, double, and long double. The type double provides at least
>   as much precision as float, and the type long double provides at least as much precision as double.
>   The set of values of the type float is a subset of the set of values of the type double; the set of values
>   of the type double is a subset of the set of values of the type long double. The value representation of
>   floating-point types is implementation-defined. Integral and floating types are collectively called arithmetic
>   types. Specializations of the standard template std::numeric_limits (18.3) shall specify the maximum
>   and minimum values of each arithmetic type for an implementation.

As for *promotions* which is the next most interesting bit:

> **4.6 Floating point promotion**
>
> **1** A prvalue of type float can be converted to a prvalue of type
>   double. The value is unchanged.
>
> **2** This conversion is called floating
>   point promotion.

Note there is nothing being said about `double` to `long double`. I'd hazard this as a slip though.

Next about conversions which is what we are interested when you go from `long double` to `double`:

> **4.8 Floating point conversions**
>
> **1** A prvalue of floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of
>   another floating point type. If the source value can be exactly
>   represented in the destination type, the result of the conversion is
>   that exact representation. If the source value is between two adjacent
>   destination values, the result of the conversion is an
>   implementation-defined choice of either of those values. Otherwise,
>   the behavior is undefined.
>
> **2** The conversions allowed as floating point
>   promotions are excluded from the set of floating point conversions.

Now, let's see the effects of *narrowing*:

> **6**. A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion
>
> [...]
>
> - from long double to double or float, or from double to float, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after
>     conversion is within the range of values that can be represented (even
>     if it cannot be represented exactly)

There are two takeaways from all this standardese:

- Combining the bit about narrowing with the bit about implementation defined conversions there may be changes in your results across platforms.
- If your intermediate results (considering multiple such results) in `long double` are in a range that cannot be represented accurately by a `double` (high or low), these can accumulate to return a different final result which you will want to return back as a `double`.

As for which is *more accurate*, I think that depends entirely on your application.